# Probability(is it possible?)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We are given 3 dice $A,B,C$, with a number from 1 to 6 written on each face. Numbers can repeat, for example $A$ can have the labels $1,1,1,2,3,6$. Let $R_A$ denote a number rolled by a roll of $A$. Define $A>B$ as $\mathbb{P}\left[R_A > R_B\right] > 1/2$. Is it possible to have 3 dice where $A>B, B>C, C>A$ ?

Comment: Yes. These are called non-transitive dice. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontransitive_dice Specifically, look at the section "Three-dice set with minimal alterations to standard dice"